# Why the_excerpt() function returns excerpt on the Home page and trimmed content in sidebar?

Tags: custom-post-types, get-posts, excerpt

I have this code to display 4 posts of type "testimonial" on the Home page:

```
<?php
            $custom_posts = get_posts([
                'numberposts' => 4,
                'post_type' => 'testimonial'
            ]);
            ?>

            <?php foreach ($custom_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>

                <article>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue reading</a>

                    <p><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pacient', TRUE); ?></p>
                </article>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works as expected. Excerpts are shown. Sunshine rainbows. Unfortunately if I move exactly the same code to the sidebar on other side no excerpts are shown. There is content trimmed down for each post instead.

In other words: This exact same code (copy/pasted) on home page produces excerpts. In the sidebar on other page it produces trimmed content with "[...]" at the end. I have no clue why. Can the problem be related to where the get_post function is called (after Query or something).

Why this function behaves differently in both cases? How do I force it to show excerpt only and not the post content. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The excerpt can't change its behaviour to suite itself

Comment: This exact same code (copy/pasted) on home page produces excerpts. In the sidebar on other page it produces trimmed content with "[...]" at the end. I have no clue why. Can the problem be related to where the get_post function is called (after Query or something).

Comment: You should add that info directly to your question in the form of an [edit]. Thank you

Comment: are you using hand-written excerpts? does your theme possibly use any filters for the excerpt?

Comment: I guess there is a filter added in functions.php which is showing full excerpt in homepage and trimmed excerpt in the sidebar. Did you check functions.php or any other file included in functions.php?

Comment: i could be something like this `add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'name_of_the_function' );`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with `the_excerpt()`. `the_excerpt()` template tag does not change its behavior by itself or change its behavior according to location. The only time `the_excerpt()` changes its behavior is when you manually filter the output through a custom function.

I most probably think that all of your misery is caused by neglet :-). Neglet to what you may ask, and the simple answer is, negletting clean up after yourself when you done, ie resetting your postdata once you've done with your custom query

Many people neglet this unmost important function [`wp_reset_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata). This is a gloden rule, always always, whenever you create a custom query with either [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) or [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), you **have to** reset your query, otherwise every other query afterwards will be affected negatively.

So, I think by resetting your postdata after your custom query (add `wp_reset_postdata` just after `endforeach`), everything will be fine

Just a point of note, don't use `:` and `endforeach`. It makes code difficult to read and to debug, and code editors can't read this as well. To make things easier in the future, rather use curly brackets (`{}`)

Comment: Many thanks for your advices. I was tinkering with it for a while. I have added `wp_reset_postdata` after all custom queries but nothing changed. I tried to remove all queries except the one and still the same code produces excerpts on static home page and trimmed content with "[...]" on page/post. I really dont understand the behaviour of this :-( I believe Wordpress is altering the custom query in some way if you are inside the post or page. Is it possible?